# Collation for international characters (Spanish), php

Tags: php, mysql, collation

I have ñ's and á's in the cells of my database. My collation is set to utf8, but on the website my characters are not displaying right.

```
Esperamos que disfrute del programa y aprenda bastantes consejos 
�tiles para padres para mejorar el desarrollo de su hijo. Tambi�n 
puede aprender de otras mam�s y ellas de usted. El Foro...
```

Displaying it via SELECT statement and then through php on the page. Let me know if you need more information. Perhaps this is a common problem?

Comment: You should set the charset in your script to UTF8 as well.

Comment: Post your code. Looks like character sets are not getting translated properly between entry, DB write, DB read, and display.

Comment: use headers header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Answer (score 1):

Try with this header at the top of your php script:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and/or the META tag as a [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through?lq=1#answer-285036) says.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: I did both things, then I finally got it working with mysqli_set_charset()

Answer (score 1):

After checking that my charset was correct, this did the trick.

```
class DBMySQL{
// ...
    private function set_connection($connection) {
        $this->_connection = $connection;
        mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8"); // VICTORY!
    }
// ...
}
```